# haggling vs bargaining

Tags: grammar

> After a brief dispute and much ***haggling***, they came to a compromise and
>   the $3,000 transaction was made.

Is haggling the same as bargaining?
Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: [this is a classical tutorial in haggling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u75XQdTxZRc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oxford Dictionaries define [haggle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/haggle?q=haggling) as "**Dispute or bargain persistently**, especially over the cost of something" and [bargain](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bargain) as "**An agreement** between two or more people or groups as to what each will do for the other"

So 'haggle' implies somewhat petty attitude and uncivilsed nature.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between haggling and bargaining is similar to the difference between arguing and discussing. Haggling and bargaining are both used to talk about something, especially prices, to reach an agreement, with the only difference that the former is a bit harsher in which there is some sort of annger, noise, disagreement or heated conversation, whereas the latter is softer, in which parties normally remain composed.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is valid!

The word *haggling* means 'a heated argument' but it is *generally* used when the argument is about *bargaining!*

[WordWebOnline](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=haggling) defines it:

> haggling (n) - *An instance of intense argument **(as in bargaining)***

So, there was a brief dispute and some heated argument to bargain before the settled the matter.